# Looking for the proof, that Tensorflow noise generation can be unreliable on GPU

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, noise

While reading the paper [Rainbow](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.02298) from DeepMind, I got stuck on the following text in the "Experimental Methods" section:

> Tensorflow noise generation can be unreliable on GPU.

That sounds surprising. Does anyone knows anything about quality of noise generated by Tensorflow and why it's "unreliable"? Is this statement still true (the paper was published on 6 Oct 2017)?

Comment: That's interesting but yes, it's hard to tell what exactly they refer to. You may consider trying to get in touch with some author, they should be able to explain the claim and maybe even tell you if it still holds (and if you do please write about it here:) ).

Comment: Makes sense. I've asked one of the authors.